# Which LLVM instructions can exit a function?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

My goal is to determine all the possible exit points from an LLVM function. I know that [terminator instructions](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#terminator-instructions) end basic blocks, either to exit the function or to branch to another part of the same function. Among the terminator instructions, I am clear on most of them:

- `ret` and `resume` exit the function
- `br`, `switch`, `indirectbr` branch to other blocks in the same function
- `invoke`, `catchswitch` related to exception control flow, and also should not exit the function
- (`unreachable` can be ignored for this purpose)

I would like to seek clarification on `catchret` and `cleanupret`. I have compiled [example exception handling code](https://github.com/mmcloughlin/hellollvm/blob/de9244a2cbfe399b354e70b44a2b28c03625890b/example.cc#L58-L81) (`clang++` on Mac and Ubuntu) and do not see these instructions in the compiled LLVM IR. Are these only used for specific ABIs?

Comment: Both those instructions appear in the example on the relevant [doc](https://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html) page.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes that's an option, but I thought it was worth a try here too.

Comment: @compor I did see that before, but on re-reading it I noticed this is specifically for windows. I have since been able to generate these instructions by compiling with `-target i386-pc-win32`.